# android button with background image and text inside

Tags: android, image, button, background

How can I create a button like this?

I want change the number of text programmatically later in app.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/de472.png]

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: You can use a `TextView`. It's clickable. It can contain a dynamic text. It can have a background, without using the button's default background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create image of that background & take one textview, set its background to this image & set text whatever you want to set.

For example your this image name is abc.png

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/abc"
    android:text="1" />
```

For setting dynamic value you can use setText method of TextView

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute in your Button XML code.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/[your background image here]"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a layout (by exemple framelayout) that will contains your image and your text, and add a listener on that layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>


(TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text).setText("HELLO");

findViewById(R.id.my_layout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Action on click
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You Should use Textview here:

Set Property of TextView like this:

```
     android:padding_left="20dp"
     android:poadding_right="20dp"
     android:padding_top="5dp"
     android:padding_bottom="5dp"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:textSize="22sp"
```